# Having done something,... vs Doing something,

Tags: difference, tense

Do these two sentences mean the same thing? If not, please elaborate.

- > Growing up in California, I experienced life that was different than most people in Mexico.
- > Having grown up in California, I experienced life different than most people in Mexico.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two sentences do not mean the same thing.  The two phrases in the first sentence are happening at the same time, while the two in the second sentence happen in sequence - one after the other.

> (While) growing up in California, I experienced...

The life that was experienced during the time that I was growing up in California was different from that in Mexico.

> Having grown up in California, I experienced...

Because I grew up in California, my experience of later life was different from people who had grown up in Mexico.

The first sentence is a comment about the way of life for a growing person in California vs one in Mexico.  The second sentence is a comment about the effect on one's point of view of the world from growing up in California vs growing up in Mexico.

Answer (score 1):

The use of the present participle "growing up' is indicative of the ongoing action. So the first sentence presented by the OP will usually be understood as " While I was growing up in California, I experienced life .....".

Besides, according to Oxford Practice Grammar (John Eastwood), you can also use either the `-ing` form of a verb or the perfect `-ing` form to give a reason. So the sentence "Growing up/Having grown up in California, I experienced life......" = Because/As I grew up in California, I experienced life.......".

So I don't think there's any difference in the meaning between the sentences presented by the OP.

Comment: Which form of the verb is "-ging"? If that a mistake, please correct it :)

Comment: Usernew, It was a typo. Thanks for pointing it out. BTW, I am surprised how you couldn't correct it because you often edit my answers.

Comment: I wanted to, but still wanted to make sure. :)